# How do I combine these two scripts and make it work to store audio files?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, audio

Good evening, I'm having trouble trying to upload an audio file when the form is submitted. the input type is named 'user_music' within the form.

I'm trying to run a check & create a unique folder name every time the audio file successfully gets submitted. So that eventually every audio file that has just been submitted gets **saved** and **moved** into the unique folder-name that has just been created. 
Then I then would like it to store the file destination of that audiofile into the "user_music" field of the datbase table "music" so that I can use it later on. 
That's all I'm trying to do.

I'm trying  to implement ***something*** like this into what I currently have, however I have no idea how to go about doing it:

```
 if (isset($_FILES['user_music'])) {
    if ((($_FILES["user_music"]["type"]=="audio/mp3") || (@$_FILES["user_music"]["type"]=="audio/ogg") || ($_FILES["user_music"]["type"]=="audio/wav"))&&($_FILES["user_music"]["size"] < 15048576)) //15 Megabyte
    {
    $safe = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    $mus_rand = substr(str_shuffle($safe), 0, 15);
    mkdir("userdata/mms/$mus_rand");
    }
```

Im trying to implement the above into what I currently have, which is this:

```
 $uploads_dir = '/userdata/mms';

        foreach ($_FILES["user_music"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
            if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                $tmp_name = $_FILES["user_music"]["tmp_name"][$key];
                $name = $_FILES["user_music"]["name"][$key];
                move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");


                $music_query = "INSERT INTO music WHERE user_music='$mus_rand/$music_name' WHERE username='$user'"

            }
        }
```

This is my connect script:

```
 $db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","Mylife2015") or die ("Couldn't   
 connect to SQL server");
 mysql_select_db("i-neo") or die("Couldn't select DB");

 session_start();
 if (isset($_SESSION['user_login'])) {
 $user = $_SESSION["user_login"];
 }
 else {
 $user = "";
 }
```

As you can see below the submit button for the entire form is named 'upl'.

This is the insert query with prepared statements (I'm still trying to get the hang of prepared statements):

```
  $upl = @$_POST['upl'];
  if ($upl){
  $query = "INSERT INTO music ( , $user, $man, $sn, $an, $sa, $um, $d) 
  VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
  $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
  $stmt->bind_param("sssssbbs", $user, $man, $sn, $an, $sa, $um, $d); // 
  bind variables

 $un = $user; // User Logged in 
 $man = "artist_name"; // Artist Name
 $sn = "audio_name"; // Audio Name
 $an = "album_name"; // Album Name
 $sa = "song_art"; // Song's Art Cover
 $um = "user_music"; // Audio File
 $d  = "d-m-y h:i:s a"; // Date

 $stmt->execute()
 }
```

**Below is just my php form and database table if needed**

This is my php form:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="artist_name" placeholder="Artist's Name"/><br/ <br/>
  <input type="text" name="audio_name" placeholder="Song Name"/><br/><br/>
  <input type="text" name="album_name" placeholder="Album Name"/><br/><br/>
  <input type="file" name="song_art" /><br/> Song Art Picture<br/>
  <input type="file" name="user_music" />Music File<br/>
  <input type="submit" name="upl" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

Lastly this is the table that is being inserted to:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `music` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `artist_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `audio_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `album_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `song_art` text NOT NULL,
  `user_music` text NOT NULL,
  `date_uplaoded` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: want a unique folder name only under your structure that only php creates, then how about an incrementing integer from a table

Comment: @Drew sorry that's not making sense to me, what do you mean?

Comment: you are looking for a unique folder name (among perhaps other things). How about a number

Comment: Well I'm not looking for a unique folder name, what I'm looking for is HOW to create those unique folders, what I proposed is arguably "unique" enough, I'm asking how do I implement it properly with what I already have.

Comment: php can create a folder with the command [mkdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php). And you can find many php  upload examples on The Stack. And you can find many insert and update mysql examples too. Perhaps you can narrow down the question to the most difficult, thus removing so much to sort thru. If I or anyone had your code running here, we could debug at different places  and see what is happening.

Comment: perhaps you need to modify the title, idk